# How to use "for loop" instead of "foreach loop" in Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-controller

```
$client = Client::all();
$infos = array();
$counter = 0;
$a_name = "ayman";
foreach($client as $cl) {
  if ($cl->name == $a_name)
    //code
  }
```

**Can I use that ? but it does'nt work !!**

```
  $count_client = $Client::count();
  for($i = 0; $i<$count_client; $i++) {
    if ($cl[i]->name == $a_name) {
          //code
     }
   }
```

It's a simple code but would know how to use "for loop" instead of "foreach loop" to set the data to an array.

Comment: It depend on what is `$client`

Comment: Post us what $client holds.

Comment: why would you want to? if it's a normal array, a foreach works fine? o.O

Comment: I get the data of Client table from my database

Comment: @AymaneLassfar is `$client` a object or a array

Comment: I assume you want to use a `for` loop so you can break out of it easy when `isExist` is true? If that's true, then you can use something like `break;` to finish a `foreach` quicker

Comment: **it's an object**

Comment: **I know that foreach is working nice but I would also to know how to use "for loop"**

Comment: `$client` is a collection. if you use for loop do you get any particular error ??

Comment: I got this error **Trying to get property 'type_miss' of non-object**

Comment: there's nothing `type_miss` in your question. it would be better if you update the question with full code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Converted your foreach to for loop

```
   $client = Client::all();
   $count = count($client);
   $a_name = "ayman";

   for($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
            if ($client[$i]->name == $a_name)
               //your code
            }
        }
```

Comment: When I use this code I got this error **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

Comment: can you just do dd($client) and show us what you are getting.

Comment: why do you have count($client) each time in loop ? you better define this as a variable rather than doing inside for loop. Always think about performance

Answer (score 1):

Try This....

```
 for ($x = 0; $x < count($client); $x++)
 {
     if($client[x]->name == $a_name)
         //.........
 }
```

Comment: Can u help me how to set the data wich I get into an associative $Array with this for loop

Comment: Where do you want to set data? Please Clear!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do This

```
   $client = Client::all();
   $a_name = "ayman";

   for($i=1; $i <= count($client) ; $i++) 
    {
            if ($client[$i]->name == $a_name)
            {
               //your code
            }
    }
```